# Workflow Scheduling in WF4

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have 7 workflow that need to execute; that need to run in certain order ? Is there any scheduling service for this in wf4 or any other approach i can use?

Ocean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an activity that derives fron NativeActivity you can schedule child activities in any order you like.  That is the closest thing to a "SchedulerService" I can think of.

However you have to know the activites you want to run at compile time.  You can only arrange the order differently using this approach.

If you don't know which activities you want to use at compile time you could use a parent/child technique I showed on my blog [WF4 How To Invoke a Child Workflow as XAML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/03/29/wf4-how-to-invoke-a-child-workflow-as-xaml.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run them sequentially in a certain order, why not just create another workflow and put all 7 of your workflows as activities in a top sequential activity?

Comment: I can not o that because their order would be changing every 2 weeks. Is there any scheduler service in Workflow 4 ?